# Riemann-Integral in terms of trapeziums

Tags: integration

Why isn't the Riemann integral evaluate in terms of trapeziums ? It would be a better method compared to rectangles.

Comment: Why "better"? And could you prove it "better" in general? Besides, rectangles are much easier to deal with.

Comment: because even though limit will finally give the same answer, but trapeziums with one side flat and one side slant, will give a better approximation and thus it should be more natural to define the integral in terms of trapeziums than rectangles.

Comment: I can't see how will they give a better approximation than rectangles, but still: it's easier with rectangles, imo.

Comment: Is it clear (for weird discontinuous functions) that a "trapezium" method converges if and only if the usual "rectangle" method converges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of the Riemann integral is a limit. Using trapeziums or rectangles
does not change the value of this limit, it is therefore natural to define the integral using the simplest formula based on rectangles.

A difference between rectangles and trapeziums appears when trying to estimate numerically the value of the limit (i.e. the value of the integral), because trapeziums yield a smaller absolute error.

Comment: Why is the limit taken in terms of rectangles and not trapeziums ?

Comment: Why doesn't it make a difference ?

Comment: @Iota: call $I$ the value of the integral (that you want to compute), $R_n$ the integral estimated by means of $n$ rectangles and $T_n$ the integral estaimated by means of $n$ trapeziums. It is known that $|I-R_n|\leq C/n^2$ and $|I-T_n|\leq C/2n^2$, where $C$ depends on the integrated function and the boundaries of the integral. When $n\to\infty$, $R_n$ and $T_n$ both converge to $I$.

Answer (score 4):

They [do actually use trapezoids in numerical methods,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) because they do give better approximation, but the Riemann sum method (with rectangle) is easier to use to prove things. To each his/her own.

Answer (score 3):

A Riemann integral is neither evaluated by rectangles nor by trapeziums, but by a certain *limiting process* involving partitions, Riemann sums, etc. The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus then allows to convert the "infinitesimal" evaluation process into  a finite "algebraic" handling of function expressions.

When the exact evaluation of an integral (i.e., expressing its value in terms of known constants) is not possible one has to resort to numerical methods. It is in this realm where it may pay to use trapezoids instead of rectangles in order to obtain more exact approximations with the same amount of numerical work.

Comment: You can say that after you have defined something, but the intuition was taken through rectangles only.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a comment to an already overly answered question, which might be useful to other people, who looks at the post.

While this holds for Riemann integrals for the reasons given in the other answers.
You cannot assume this for other variants integrals. What I have in mind is stochastic integrals. In this case, the trapezium and the triangle give rises to DIFFERENT notions of integrals/calculus, namely Stratonovich and Ito integrals, respectively.

Moral of the story is that do not assume it is okay in other situations that is not Riemann integration. Certainly not if the integrator is random.